# Smarty / PHP I want to keep one item in dropdown selected, but with smarty it doesnt work

Tags: php, smarty

In my forum when I add a topic, I have a dropdown with all possible categories. When I post and one of the text fields is empty there comes an error, and I want to keep the selected item in the dropdown selected.

I did it before but not with Smarty. Can somebody see what I am doing wrong?

```
$query_cat = "
    SELECT
        fcID
        ,fcName
    FROM
        forum_categories
    ";
    $exec_cat = mysql_query($query_cat);    
    while($categories = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec_cat))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['category']))
        {
            $selected = ' selected';
        }
        else
        {
            $selected = '';
        } 
    }
    $this->view->assign('selected', $selected);

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')  
    {  
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec_cat);
        $subject = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['subject']));
        $content = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['content']));

        $query_add_topic = "
        INSERT INTO
            forum_topics
        (
            ftDate
            ,fcID
            ,fuID
            ,ftSubject
            ,ftMessage
        )
        VALUES
        (
            NOW()
            ,'".$_POST['category']."'
            ,'".$_SESSION['userid']."'
            ,'".$subject."'
            ,'".$content."'
        )
        ";
        $exec_add_topic = mysql_query($query_add_topic);
    }
    else
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec_cat))
        {
            $entries[] = $row;
            $this->view->assign('entries', $entries);
        }
    }
```

And smarty

```
<table width=100%>
<tr>
    <td>Onderwerp:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="50"><input type="text" name="subject"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Categorie type</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><select name="category">
    {foreach from=$entries item=entry}
            <option value="{$entry.fcID}"{$selected}>{$entry.fcName}</option>
    {/foreach}
        </select>   
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="text"><textarea name="content" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="send" value="Verstuur"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Smarty tag for creating the `<option>` tags inside a select, `{html_options}`.  The documentation for it is [here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.options.tpl).  Besides not having to build your own loop in the template, you can also specify the selected value as a parameter, which you can pass in from PHP through your $smarty object.  That will let you create a `<select>` with minimal effort and maximum smarty goodness, easily passing in the previously selected value for your topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
Instead of this

<select name="category">
    {foreach from=$entries item=entry}
        <option value="{$entry.fcID}"{$selected}>{$entry.fcName}</option>
    {/foreach}
</select>

You can use 

 <select name="category">
      {html_options options = $entries selected = $entries.fcName}
 </select>

hope so it will work for you
```